# node js giving "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" on VPS machine

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I am using Phantom JS to load a third party URL. Then there is an node+express server with "phantom" module, which is returning back the htmls from Phantom JS.

The code works perfect in my mac, but when I try to run it in VPS, node is giving

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
function scrape(url, func){

var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create('--load-images=no', function(ph){

    return ph.createPage(function(page){
        page.set('settings.loadImages', false) ;
        return page.open(url, function(status){
            //page.injectJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', function() {
                return page.evaluate((function(){

                    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
                        links   = document.getElementsByTagName('link'),
                        images  = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
                        objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');

                    for(i in objects){                      
                        if((obj = objects[i]) && obj.data){
                            if(obj.getAttribute('data') != obj.data){
                                obj.setAttribute('data', obj.data);

                                var params = obj.getElementsByTagName('param');
                                for(var j in params){
                                    if((par = params[j]) && par.value){

                                        console.log(par.name);

                                        if(par.getAttribute('value') != par.value){
                                            par.setAttribute('value', par.value);
                                        }

                                        if(par.name == "allowscriptaccess" ){
                                            par.setAttribute('value', "always");
                                            par.value = "always";
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }                               
                    }                           

                    for(i in scripts){                      
                        if((script = scripts[i]) && script.src){
                            if(script.getAttribute('src') != script.src){
                                script.setAttribute('src', script.src);
                            }
                        }                               
                    }

                    for(i in links){
                        if((link = links[i]) && link.href ){
                            if(link.getAttribute('href') != link.href){
                                link.setAttribute('href', link.href);
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    for(i in images){
                        if((image = images[i]) && image.src){
                            if(image.getAttribute('src') != image.src){
                                image.setAttribute('src', image.src);
                            }
                        }                               
                    }


                    var baseTag = document.getElementsByTagName('base');

                    if(baseTag.length == 0){
                        var baseTag = '<base id="test" href="'+ document.domain +'" />';
                        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head');

                        head[0].innerHTML = baseTag + head[0].innerHTML;
                    }

                    return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;

                }), function(result){
                    ph.exit(); (func)(result); 
                });
            //});                   
        });
    });
});
}
exports.scrape = scrape;
```